# Switch gets toggled by itself when gone off screen in ListView - CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement, android-cursoradapter, recycle

I am having trouble figuring this one out.

**I have a ListView with CursorAdapter and if item goes offscreen the switch resets it self**. I have a listener onCheckedChangeListener set on the switch, which triggers the listener implemented by hosting fragment that updates a field in database table and requeries the whole thing (contentResolver.notifyChange()).

I know this is kinda usual issue with check boxes, but I still cant get it working.

```
public class FilterCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public interface OnSwitchToggledListener {
        public void onSwitchToggled(int id, boolean isActivated);
    }

    private OnSwitchToggledListener listener;

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.keywordTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.keyword_text_view);
        holder.cathegoryTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cathegory_text_view);
        holder.activateSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_activate);
        view.setTag(holder);

        return view;

    }


    public void bindView(View row, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        holder.keywordTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArticleProvider.COLUMN_KEYOWRD)));

        final int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArticleProvider.COLUMN_FILTER_ID));
        String cathegory = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArticleProvider.COLUMN_CATHEGORY));
        int isActivated = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArticleProvider.COLUMN_ACTIVATED));

        holder.cathegoryTextView.setText(string);
        holder.activateSwitch.setChecked(isActivated == 1);
        holder.activateSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    listener.onSwitchToggled(id, isChecked);
                }

        });
    }

     private class ViewHolder {

        public TextView keywordTextView;
        public TextView cathegoryTextView;
        public Switch activateSwitch;

    }

}

public class FilterListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnSwitchToggledListener {

    @Override
    public void onSwitchToggled(int id, boolean isActivated) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "ID: " + id + " isActivated: " + isActivated);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ArticleProvider.COLUMN_ACTIVATED, isActivated);
        resolver.update(ArticleProvider.FILTERS_URI, values, ArticleProvider.COLUMN_FILTER_ID + "=" + id, null);

    }
}
```

*From the logs it seems that the setOnCheckedChangeListener listener inside bindView gets triggered on it self.*

How do I fix this one? Also I would like to note that I am using SwitchCompatLibrary (https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you face this problem, you need to add remove the listener before setting it again

```
holder.activateSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with this for about three hours today. As soon as it moved off screen, it changed. So, I ended up abandoning the`onCheckedChanged` listener and instead used:

```
mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.i(TAG, "isChecked:");
    }
});
```

Now it works perfect.